# Laravel error log 404 from another domain

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, http-status-code-404

I'm not sure how to interpret something I'm seeing in the logs of my Laravel application. I have set up the following code in order to log the requested URL that results in a 404:

```
App::missing(function($e){
        $url = Request::fullUrl();
        Log::warning("404 for URL: $url");
});
```

My app is hosted on the domain: `example.com`, but in my log I see an entry that says:

```
[2015-01-10 22:18:41] production.WARNING: 404 for URL: http://s1.bdstatic.com/r/www/cache/static/home/img/logos/nuomi_ade5465d.png [] []
```

I don't understand how this is possible for me to see log entries for requests to URL's that are not on my domain. Does anyone know how to explain this?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/653479/strange-access-requests) looks like something is scanning for open proxies...